# Generating HTML templates, Converting them To a PDF, Then Returning To Client Via A Webservice

Tags: web-services, pdf-generation, html-rendering

So, I need to be able to return a PDF composed of hundreds of HTML templates for printing purposes, from a web service. It seems like a daunting task, and I have literally no familiarity with any of the technologies in this domain (aside from rendering HTML using a template library).

My idea is to pull the necessary data from the db, iterate through it and generate all of the html, create a large pdf using some library, and then send it back to the user. Is this going to be impossible? Does anyone have any experience doing something like this and can recommend an alternative approach?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Do you mean you literally have hundreds of template types, or is it hundreds of documents combined into a PDF?  If templates do you already have the hundreds of different layouts or are you yet to create them?

Comment: I think you're trying to do something that is demonstrated in this talk: http://itextpdf.com/summit.php#talk3